# new domain computer dragging down whole office network

Tags: networking, internet, windows-domain, microsoft-surface-pro

I've got a problem that I'd like to share as we're stumped...  I'll start at the beginning.

In the office, we are pretty average I guess - about 20 windows computers on the network in all, all on our work domain, pretty varied selection....  we have desktops, laptops, tablets, notebooks, running windows 7, 8, 10, we have a server with Windows 2008 small business server installed.

Anyhow, 3 guys recently got new computers as theirs were getting old (we're talking 7 year old lenovo's running windows vista / 7!!!)   and the company bought 3 brand new Microsoft Surface Pro's for the - supposedly the most amazing best computer according to Micrsoft!   I won't mention the endless problems we've had with them - another story.

One guy dropped his, and got it replaced, brand new one.  Ever since he's had it, it's slowed down the internet speed in the office massively.

Whenever his particular surface pro is in the office, the network slows down to around 0.5 - 2 Mbps and a ping of around 1000ms or more.  Every time he's out the office, the network is fine, running around 9-13 Mbps, a ping of between 30-60ish.  This is absolutely without exception and it's definitely an issue connected with his device.

Our IT company (who generally don't seem to be especially clued up about computers and their customer service is shocking) have checked it out for a day in their offices and they insist that there's nothing wrong with the Surface Pro.  We've tried various things here, including swapping the docking station for another one, routing the network through different plug on the network switch.  I've tried to reinstall the drivers but the packages I downloaded came up with an error saying "The targeted OS 10.0.15063 does not match the current OS 10.0.14393.0."  and aborted the installation.  Nothing we tried has made any difference at all to the issue.

Does anyone have any ideas at all what could be causing this, or what else we can check??  It's affecting the whole office and we're running out of ideas and patience!!

Would really appreciate any tips or hints that could help!  Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I've been running a network monitor, and although Onedrive is not installed, it shows Onedrive is still downloading 8-10GB a week!  Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Has anyone run any network tools such as WireShark to determine if the user's machine is doing any downloading/sharing that they're (un)aware of? And the sources/traffic type generated?

Comment: You could check whether the replaced PC is actually generating massive traffic - possibly downloading updated from the Microsoft website. Open up Resource Monitor and have a look at the Network tab. On a side not, you might want to ask on [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com), which is more geared towards IT from a company/enterprise point of view.

Comment: If the Surface is running 10.0.15063 it means its running 1703 instead of 1607.  Have your IT department install 1607.

Comment: @Ramhound - is this the OS version?  or is it drivers version?  and how would I check this on the other Surface pro's we have in the office?

Comment: *is this the OS version?* - `10.0.15063` is Windows 10 1703 and `10.0.14393.0` is Windows 10 1607.  If you are unfamilar with Windows 10 feature updates, please so do some research on the subject, or as suggest allow your IT department to handle it.  As a non-Administrator you won't be able to solve the problem you current face anyways.

Comment: Sorry - I don't commit every windows update to memory as they come out!  @Kinnectus I've been running glasswire on the pc , I'll check it later and update if there's any notable results on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glasswire was the problem solver for us here - after running glasswire for a while we noticed that Onedrive maxed out the network useage whenever it was in the office - even though the user didn't use Onedrive, didn't know he had it and didn't have anything stored in it.  Never solved why it was doing this, but in the end we forced uninstalled it and it didn't give any more problems after that.